# MySql find result and order result by number of item satisfying conditions

Tags: mysql

I have one table "set" have n-n relationship with table "item":

```
set(id, img)
set_rel_item(set_id, item_id)
item(id, name, img, price)
```

And i want to find set which have item can have name like: "item1" or "item2" or "item3". And order them by the number of item satisfying conditions. IE set have 3 item satisfying conditions "item1", "item2", "item3" will be first, then set have 2 item satisfying conditions, lastly set have 1 item satisfying conditions

Can someone help me, thank you

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I dont understand sir

Comment: He suggest you provide more data on what you have and what you need.  Just read the linked article

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT s.id
 FROM set s
 JOIN set_rel_item sri
   ON s.id = sri.set_id
 JOIN item i
   ON sri.item_id = i.id
 WHERE i.name in ('item1','item2','item3')
 GROUP BY s.id
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT i.name) >= 1
 ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT i.name) DESC
```

Comment: thank you but group by only display first item of each set, how can i display all item of each set

Comment: You need to provide some example of data and what result you want. Your question say you only need set.id